# Automatic slide switching (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

**I can not understand why the timer does not work, and the text does not scroll automatically.**

I tried to do so:

```
ForEach(0..<numberText)
```

But I got such an error:

```
Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'some View' conform to 'TableRowContent'
```

Full code:

```
let numberText = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"]

struct TextNew: View {
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var index = 0
    
    let textdata = TextData.getAllText()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            TabView(selection: $index) {
                
                ForEach(numberText, id: \.self) { num in
                    
                    Text("\(num)")
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .tag(num)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)
                    
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .frame(height: 80)
            .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    index = index < numberText.count ? index + 1 : 0
                    
                }
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help, I'm new

Comment: Your `Timer` runs fine with this code. You can test it by writing `print("Timer fired")` within your `onReceive` closure. What's unclear is what you expect to happen with `index = index < numberText.count ? index + 1 : 0`, since `index` isn't actually *used* anywhere in the UI.

Comment: @jnpdx Then why doesn't the text change automatically?

Comment: @jnpdx I expect the text to scroll automatically after a given timer, but this does not happen

Comment: Looks like @burnsi beat me to a possible solution, but to elaborate on why their answer works, your `tag` type has to match the `selection` parameter type. Right now, you're trying to compare a `String` to an `Int`. Also worth mentioning that `.self` is potentially dangerous as an `id` unless the data will never change (which, to be fair, in your example, is true).

Comment: @jnpdx thank you for the explanation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct TextNew: View {
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var index = 1
    @State private var selectedNum: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            TabView(selection: $selectedNum) {
                
                ForEach(numberText, id: \.self) { num in
                    Text("\(num)")
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            
            .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    index = index < numberText.count ? index + 1 : 1
                    selectedNum = numberText[index - 1]
                }
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation:

The reason for this not working is the type mismatch between your `.tag` and the `$index` in your `TabView` declaration. These have to match. By the way you do not need the `.tag` here as you are setting it to `.self` in your `ForEach` loop.

Comment: thank you very much ! do you know how to loop?

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of @burnsi 's answer.

```
//Properties

    @StateObject var vm = HomeVVM()
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var index = 1
    @State private var selectedNum: String = ""


//Tabview


TabView(selection: $selectedNum) {
  ForEach(vm.trendingItems) { item in
    HomeSliderItem(image: item.getImage(), text: item.getName()).tag(item.id.uuidString)
  }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page)
.onChange(
  of: selectedNum,
  { oldValue, newValue in
    let newIndex = vm.trendingItems.firstIndex(where: { it in
      it.id.uuidString == selectedNum
    })
    index = newIndex != nil ? newIndex! : 1
  }
)
.onReceive(
  timer,
  perform: { _ in
    withAnimation {
      index = index < vm.trendingItems.count ? index + 1 : 1
      let newCandidate = index - 1
      if newCandidate > -1 && newCandidate < vm.trendingItems.count {
        selectedNum = vm.trendingItems[newCandidate].id.uuidString
      }
    }
  })
```

✅ It makes sure your app doesn't crash due to an ArrayOutOfBounds exception 
✅ Synchronized with the user's scrolling of the TabView